# Problem with using remove, pop, del on list in Python

Tags: python, list, function

```
a = [10, 12, 14]
b = a
b.remove(12) 
print(a)
print(b)
```

Result is:

```
[10, 14]
[10, 14]
```

The result is same when I use pop, del function

It is also same when I delete from a (a.remove, a.pop, del a)

What I want is (like disconnection):

```
[10, 12, 14]
[10, 14]
```

It seems like remove function deletes the element in the original list too

Comment: `a` and `b` are both references to the same list.  See [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: `b=a.copy()` will solve your problem.

Comment: or just `b = a[:]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to reference a **copy** of `a` with `b`, not the same list, so just copy it:

```
from copy import copy
a = [10, 12, 14]
b = copy(a)
b.remove(12) 
print(a)
print(b)

[10, 12, 14]
[10, 14]
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/AptHotpinkSubweb)